# Mallocing an unsigned char array to store ints

Tags: arrays, char, segmentation-fault, malloc, typedef

I keep getting a segmentation fault when i test the following code. I am currently unable to find an answer after having searched the web.

```
a = (byte *)malloc(sizeof(byte) * x ) ; 

for( i = 0 ; i < x-1 ; i++ )
{
scanf("%d", &y ) ;
a[i] = y ;
}
```

Both y and x are initialized. X is the size of the array determined by the user.
The segmentation fault is on the second to last integer to be added, i found this by adding 
printf("roar") ; before setting a[i] to y and entering one number at a time. 
Byte is a typedef of an unsigned char.

Note: I've also tried using

```
a[i] = (byte)y ;
```

A is ininitalized as follows

```
byte *a ;
```

If you need to view the entire code it is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sort.h"

int p_cmp_f () ;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{
  int x, y, i, choice ;

  byte *a ;

  while( choice !=2 )
    {
      printf( "Would you like to sort integers?\n1. Yes\n2. No\n" ) ;

      scanf("%d", &choice ) ;

      switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
      printf( "Enter the length of the array: " ) ;

  scanf( "%d", &x ) ;

  a =  (byte *)malloc(sizeof( byte ) * x ) ;

  printf( "Enter %d integers to add to the array: ", x ) ;

  for( i = 0 ; i < x -1 ; i++ )
    {
    scanf( "%d", &y ) ;

    a[i] = y ;
    }
  switch( choice )
    {
    case 1:
      bubble_sort( a, x, sizeof(int), p_cmp_f ) ;

      for( i = 0 ; i < x ; i++ )
    printf( "%d", a[i] ;


      break ;

    case 2:
      selection_sort( a, x, sizeof(int),  p_cmp_f ) ;

      for( i = 0 ; i < x; i++ )
    printf( "%d", a[i] ;


      break ;

    case 3:
      insertion_sort( a, x, sizeof(int), p_cmp_f ) ;

      for( i = 0 ; i < x ; i++ )
    printf( "%d", a[i] ;


      break ;

    case 4: 
      merge_sort( a, x, sizeof(int), p_cmp_f ) ;

      for( i = 0 ; i < x ; i++ )
    printf( "%d", a[i] ;

      break ;

    case 5:
      quick_sort( a, x, sizeof(int), p_cmp_f ) ;

      for( i = 0 ; i < x ; i++ )
    printf( "%d", a[i] ;


      break ;

    default:
      printf("Enter either 1,2,3,4, or 5" ) ;

      break ;
    }
    case 2:
      printf( "Thank you for using this program\n" ) ;

      return 0 ;

      break ;

    default: 
      printf( "Enter either 1 or 2: " ) ;

    break ;
    }
}
  free(a) ;

  return 0 ;
}

int p_cmp_f( byte *element1, byte *element2 )
{
  return *((int *)element1) - *((int *)element2) ;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how a is declared? If a is declared as anything other than a byte you won't be allocating enough space.

Comment: That should be OK. Also check that y is declared as an int. It might be worth adding the extra code to your question for anyone else that comes along.

Answer (score 1):

Running that code I got a debug exception because the initial value of choice isn't defined, you should add

```
choice = 0;
```

Before the while loop. Also the following statement:

```
for( i = 0 ; i < x -1 ; i++ )
```

Should be:

```
for( i = 0 ; i < x; i++ )
```

If you're using a compiler that detects uninitialized memory either of those two could have caused the exception. It worked fine for me under Visual Studio 2010 after making those changes. I'd also recommend turning on the maximum warning level for your compiler, it probably would have picked up that first situation.

I'm not sure if it's what you intended but in the nested cases for the inner case statement the final break is missing so it goes to the "Thank you for using this program" part always instead of looping back for another choice. Also because a return statement is used to exit the function rather than just allowing it to drop to the bottom free(a) never gets called.

Rather than nesting the cases I'd recommend breaking into two functions, leave the top-level case where it is and then have a function like perform_sort that has a case to do the correct sort based on the user input. That will make it all a lot easier to follow and you can also print the results after calling that function instead of duplicating the loops to print the results.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i still get a segmentation fault. Only now it is on the final entry.

Comment: I've just added a few more suggestions, not sure it will fix it but breaking up the code that way will make it much easier to follow and make sure the memory gets freed.